# How do I Include and ThenInclude on list of <base-class>containing derived classes (EF7-beta8)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Say you have a class containing a list of some base-class and you want to include something defined on a derived class:

```
public class Cart {
  public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product {
  public string Name {get;set}
}

public class DeliveryProduct : Product {
  public Address DeliveryAddress {get;set;}
}

public class SomeOtherProduct : Product {
  public SomeOtherClass Something {get;set;}
}
```

I can't simply do ***productContext.Cart.Include(c => c.Products).ThenInclude(p => p.DeliveryProduct)*** because there's no DeliveryProduct on the base-type Product.

Comment: Why do you need the `.ThenInclude(...)` part? The `DeliveryProducts` are a concrete realization of the abstract `Product` class, not a subclass.

Comment: Ok, updated sample code, but I need .ThenInclude to include whatever I need from the DeliveryProduct (or the SomeOtherProduct above).

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely possible what you want to do. What about: http://pastebin.com/PMS3mcPy

Then you can load it using  `productContext.Cart.Include(c => c.DeliveryProducts).Include(c => c.SomeOtherProducts)`

Comment: But c (the cart) doesn't have DeliveryProducts but Products, which can be of type DeliveryProduct - but when I call Include(c => c.Products) I will only get the base-class (Product) in ThenInclude(product => p...) which doesn't have DeliveryAddress. What I can tell there's no way to say .Include<DeliveryProduct>(cart => cart.Products).ThenInclude(deliveryProduct => deliveryProduct.DeliveryAddress).

Comment: Did you click the pastebin link? I've added properties for DeliveryProducts and SomeOtherProducts.